# How to override built-in VSCode commands via an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

According to [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65876#issuecomment-451911036), what I need should be this piece of code:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('type', (args) => {
  console.log(`type with args`, args)
  return vscode.commands.executeCommand('default:type', args)
})
```

This should allow for overriding the built-in `type` command and even call the original command if needed via `default:` prefix. However, I get this error, which implies otherwise.

[image]

Is there any alternative way of achieving the desired override or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Vim extension installed?

Comment: Yes, I copied/pasted your code and it works fine for me - no errors.  So you probably have another extension that has registered the `type` command.  Vim or neovim are the usual culprits.

Comment: Yes, that will be it, thanks guys. So to summarize, it's possible to override built-in vscode commands as long as they are not overriden by another extension already, which makes sense I guess.

Edit: I tried to override the desired command `vscode.diff`, but getting the error again, even with all extensions disabled, so I guess it's not going to be that easy.

Comment: Did you resolve that? I'm looking in this area too. TY